# Removing specific classes from all div elements of certain format

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to remove all classes starting with nf-

[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeCEE.png)

JSfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zapjelly/fda3Lm84/11/

I have the following HTML/JS:

```js
var nfClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-nf [class*="nf-"]');

Array.prototype.map.call(nfClasses, function(elem) {
  Array.prototype.map.call(elem.classList, function(classStr) {
    if (classStr.match(/^nf\-/)) elem.classList.remove(classStr);
  });
});
```

```html
<p>Remember to inspect element on the input below</p>
<div class="custom-nf">
  <div class="input nf-input-outer nf-validation">
    <div class="nf-container">
      <div class="nf-outer nf-outer-input nf-outer-validation">
        <div class="nf-middle">
          <div class="nf-inner">
            <label for="dummy" class="nf-label"></label>
            <input id="dummy" type="text" class="nf-input">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: querySelectorAll is not collecting the classes you required, Try the fix there to select the required classes

Comment: @PatrickEvans I don't think that's a duplicate. The OP is trying to remove specific *classes* from an element. They are not trying to remove elements like in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), the [`.classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) returns a **live** [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) of the class attributes of the element. The key point is that the list is **live**, which means that as you remove classes, you are inadvertently skipping over some of the other classes while iterating over them.

Based on the code that you provided, you could simply create a copy of the class list so that it is no longer live. You can do this by calling the `.slice()` method:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bnLcece6/)

```
var nfClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-nf [class*="nf-"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(nfClasses, function(element) {
  var classListCopy = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.classList);
  classListCopy.forEach(function(className) {
    if (className.match(/^nf\-/)) {
      element.classList.remove(className);
    }
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you could also iterate over the classes backwards. In doing so, none of the classes will be skipped:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/v0pobyu1/)

```
var nfClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-nf [class*="nf-"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(nfClasses, function(element) {
  for (var i = element.classList.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (element.classList[i] && element.classList[i].match(/^nf\-/)) {
      element.classList.remove(element.classList[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

---

A third option would be to just use a regular expression to replace the classes:

```
var nfClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-nf [class*="nf-"]');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(nfClasses, function(element) {
  element.className = element.className.replace(/\bnf-\S+\b/g, '').trim();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Josh! Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Updated inner loop to slice as suggested and working now

https://jsfiddle.net/zapjelly/fda3Lm84/12/

```
var nfClasses = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-nf [class*="nf-"]');

Array.prototype.map.call(nfClasses,
    function(elem){
    Array.prototype.slice.call(elem.classList).map(
        function(classStr){
            if(classStr.match(/^nf\-/)) elem.classList.remove(classStr);
        })
  });
```